# How to make a scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot

I would like to make a point cloud with these two columns but I can't do it, can you help me?

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
members = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv")

x = members["member_id"]
y = members["death_height_metres"]

plt.scatter(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `plt.show()` at the end. It will show you graph then.

Comment: Even with the plt.show(), it doen't work

Comment: I think problem is you have 76519 entrys and it stucks because of huge amunt of data. I tryed and it stopped responding because of large data.

Answer (score 0):

All your column values for height_metres are NaN

```
members["death_height_metres"].isna().sum()
```

Gives:75451

You need to check your data.